# Приложения для iPad: можно ли "выключить" оптимизацию для iPad Pro?

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, xcode7, ios8

У меня есть приложение написаное только для iPad другим человеком, который уже не работает здесь. Он использовал `storyboards` и `autolayout`, но сделано это было так что `autolayout` работает только частично. Когда приложение запускается на обычном iPad или iPad-мини, оно выглядит нормально. Но, если я запускаю его на iPad Pro, проблемы с `autolayout` тут-же проявляются. Приложение можно использовать, но выглядит это ужасно. Мой вопрос таков, можно ли "выключить" оптимизацию приложения для iPad Pro? Например, как приложения написаные только для iPhone выглядят на iPad: просто в увеличенном виде?

Я использую **Xcode 7.2.1** и **Deployment Target** выставлена на **8.3**

Answer (score 1):

Выключить автолэйаут для конкретного устройства стандартными средствами xcode нельзя. В случае iPad-iPhone все приложения, у которых deployment выставлен только iPhone могут работать на iPad с возможностью масштабирования в 2 раза.

Что вы можете попробовать сделать: в своих классах переписать метод `layoutSubviews` и для всех девайсов кроме iPad Pro вызывать super, а для iPad Pro либо ничего не делать, либо написать полностью кастомный метод.

А вообще наверно лучшим подходом будет исправить все констрейнты, чтобы нормально работало на всех устройствах.